# Using common function in multiple activity android

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, extends

I want to use `common function` in `multiple activity`. How can I achieve this?

In my application I am displaying a `Dialog box` which have some data coming from some api. And this Dialog box, used in multiple activities. `Right now I have implemented same Dialog box in all activities`. Now I want common Dialog box for all activities. `I am using this Dialog box in activity as well in adapter`.

How could I do this? Using `extends` or using `fragment`.
I am already extending some class so I can not extend again( As I read, we can not extends more than one class.).

Also I want to pass some value to this function and based on `return` value I want to call another function.

```
private boolean allGroupsEdit(final String type) {
    String allGroups = "allGroups";
    final String url = Constants.CONSTANT_SERVER_URL + Constants.CONSTANT_GET_GROUPS_URL;
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.please_wait));
    dialog.show();

    StringRequest allGroupsRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String s) {
            final SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesRemember = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            sessionGroupId = sharedPreferencesRemember.getString(Constants.CONSTANT_session_group_id, "");

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray(Constants.CONSTANT_data);
                int a = jsonArray.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject schObj = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                    schData = schObj.optJSONArray(Constants.CONSTANT_data);
                }
            dialog.dismiss();
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_checkbox_options);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

               if(..someting){
                 editPublicComments(type);
               }else{
                 editPublicPosts(type);
               }
              }catch(){}
       }
  }
```

**Note:** This a very long function so I am pasting some code for basic understand. If u need anything more detail let me know. Thanks in advance and editing and suggestions are welcome.

**Edit_1:** I want this whole function to be common.
**Edit_2:** How to return value to activity from utils ?

**Edit_3:** Now I created a static function in a class and I am able to call it from my activity. Now I want call another function based on common function result. (I am using `SharedPreferences` to store value of common function).

But in my activity where I called a common function, I doesn't execute common function first. It call another function then It call common function and after completing common method, it doesn't call another method again.

All I want to call another function based on result of common function which is `true or false`

```
 boolean abab = CommonGroupBox.allGroupsEdit(context,"share", selectedPostId, localGrpArray);
 if (abab){
   boolean pubFlag = pref.getBoolean("isPublicFlag", false);
   String qType = pref.getString("questionType","0");
   if (pubFlag) {
      editPublicComments(qType);
   }else{
      ediComments(qType);
   }
 else{
   boolean pubFlag = pref.getBoolean("isPublicFlag", false);
   String qType = pref.getString("questionType","0");
   if (pubFlag) {
     PublicComments(qType);
   }else{
     Comments(qType);
   }
  }
```

Here it doesn't call `CommonGroupBox.allGroupsEdit` firsts. It is called after if and else loop.

Comment: Create a `Utility`  class and put all the common method their and use throughout your application.

Comment: Thankx for ur responce @Rustam. I am new to android. How to create utility class and how to call it as well pass variable to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a normal java class

```
 public class Utility {

    //your common method
    public static void showDialog(Context context,int type){

       //TODO task
    }
}
```

Now you can use the `showDialog` method any where in your application

```
Utility.showDialog(ctx,type);
```

Comment: Can I call another function from it ? or Can I get data from it ?

Comment: yes you can. if you want some data back from your method then mention the `return type` of method accordingly

Comment: you can create multiple models and create an instances in the Utility Class @Rustam created to pass data across your application.

Comment: hey thankx for reply. I want to call another function based on common function result. But now I am calling common function but another function is called before return value from common function. I am using if and else and It call it before the value return @Orvenito

Comment: Sorry, can you please add an edit to your question and include what you want to add to your common class for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class which extends AppCompatActivity, implement your method there and make all your other activities extend this class:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected boolean allGroupsEdit(final String type) {
        // ...
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

Then implement your activity as :

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        allGroupsEdit("Some type");
    }
...
```

Comment: As i said I am already extending some call. So technically I can not extend another class(As I read).

Answer (score 0):

To create a Utility Class:

1) Create a Java file with name AppUtil which extends Activity.

2) Select a common method that you are going to use in your Application.

3) Write the function in AppUtil java file

4) Make all the function as static in your Java file so it can be easy to call inside your activity (example: AppUtil.yourMethod() )

5) Pass the context of your Activity.

Here is a simple example to check internet connection:

```
public class AppUtilities extends Activity {

public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && 
    netInfo.isAvailable();
  }
}
```

And you can easily call this method from anywhere in your Application
example ::

```
AppUtilities.isInternetConnected(YourActivity.this);
```